# Should the natural homomorphism of field extensions $i: k \to F$ in this proposition be written as $k \to k[x] \to F$ or $k \to k[t] \to F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

From *Algebra: Chapter $0$* by Aluffi:

> [image]

---

**Since $F=k[t]/(f(t))$, is the composition in the last line correct?**

**Wouldn't it make more sense to write $k \to k[t] \to F$?**

Comment: Indeed, this appears to be a typo.